# Logins mapped to dropped database sql server

Tags: sql-server

I was told to `delete` the logins that are mapped to a database `ABC` but unfortunately the database `ABC` has been **dropped and no backups exist**.

Is it possible to find the `logins` that WERE mapped to `ABC`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

`SELECT * FROM syslogins WHERE dbname = 'ABC'`

If there are logins still using that as their default database, this should help you find them.  However, if the users had a default database of `master` and the application performed a `USE ABC` command, then you'll have no way of knowing they were tied to the application.  It's only if the application was kind enough to create your SQL logins with a default database of `'ABC'` will you be able to track things down.